Count the possible folds of an n² grid
Inspired by this recent video, I figured we could get a new value for the OEIS sequence A001418 with a fastest-code challenge. There's a sample java implementation here if you change the 2 on line 159 to an n (see A001418).
For this challenge, your code will be ran with n=6 on my linux pc (12 cores, 31 G). Your score is the real time output by the bash command time $lang $file 6, but to be considered valid it should still give correct values for inputs other than 6. Calculating the 6th element using the sample implementation takes ~20 min and uses one core on my computer.
For a more complete (but dry) statement of the problem, see this pdf. To understand why it's not as simple as just multiplying some numbers together, this website has images to go along with some explanation. I highly encourage you to fold up at least a 2x3 and 3x3 piece of paper yourself to understand what the code is doing.
Description of the sequence
Consider a square paper map which has been folded many times such that it's no longer possible to determine the original intended folding. The map has n-1 folds along each direction, making it a n by n grid. This sequence enumerates the number of possible unique ways the map be folded into a single stack of leaves.
Stealing images from the site mentioned earlier, say you start with a 2x2 map:

there are 8 unique ways of folding it into a stack:

Test cases
1 1
2 8
3 1368
4 300608
5 186086600
6 123912532224
7 129950723279272
8 some n in 2^14*14!<n<64!
  I think 24! also works as a ceiling, but I can't prove it

off-diagonal entries were asked for, so here's a the single digits:
1xn:
1, 2, 6, 16, 50, 144, 462, 1392, 4536, 14060, 46310, 146376, 485914, 1557892, 5202690, 16861984, 56579196, 184940388, 622945970, 2050228360, 6927964218, 22930109884, 77692142980, 258360586368, 877395996200, 2929432171328, 9968202968958, 33396290888520, 113837957337750
2xn:
2, 8, 60, 320, 1980, 10512, 60788, 320896, 1787904, 9381840, 51081844, 266680992, 1429703548, 7432424160, 39409195740, 204150606976, 1073644675448, 5545305620064
3xn:
6, 60, 1368, 15552, 201240, 2016432, 21582624, 201060768, 1944012744, 17257455960, 156760071600, 1346073913440, 11734199738820, 98420246759688
4xn:
16, 320, 15552, 300608, 6139920, 94808928, 1483144208, 20245128960, 276086428128, 3488202663200
5xn:
50, 1980, 201240, 6139920, 186086600, 4068298440, 87202967460, 1604927934560
6xn:
144, 10512, 2016432, 94808928, 4068298440, 123912532224, 3529382877048
7xn:
462, 60788, 21582624, 1483144208, 87202967460, 3529382877048
8xn:
1392, 320896, 201060768, 20245128960, 1604927934560
9xn:
4536, 1787904, 17257455960, 3488202663200

If possible, I would appreciate if your program can also save its state to a file that it can read once a day or something -- while I do get long uptimes with my computer, the estimated 3-10 years that the video gives for calculating #8 is much longer than I can go without rebooting.
Scoreboard
gsitcia,     rust, 4.229s for case 6, 95m39.682s for case 7
138 Aspen, python, 30m28.908s for case 6


sandbox

Could you add a basic description of the sequence to the question body?

I was sure I had added an oeis link, but I guess not. I attempted a description, but I would still recommend looking at the video or the website linked since I'm not good at explaining things

I don't quite understand the question. It seems a raw DP which would complete instantly so I doubt

@l4m2 yeah, I'm bad at explaining things, that's why I keep saying to go to the links. if you try it yourself for like 15 min you quickly see that the obvious methods either double-count or miss a ton of cases

Suggest table when it's rectangular, aka m and n differ

I thought each time fold and convert to smaller version, and this should be an upperbound(e.g. for 4x1, flipping both 1 and 4 to middle are unordered), but link says that 2x3 is 60 strates, more than 48 I get

@l4m2 this question specifically asks about the n² case, but I can add diagonal cases for testing purposes. if you're not seeing all the 2x3 cases, you can try looking here where you can see all 60 cases up close, or following the instructions closely at the link in the post. feel free to move this to a chat if you have more questions, I'll help as much as I can

Rust
main.rs
use std::{collections::HashSet, fs, io::Write, path::PathBuf, sync::{Arc, Mutex}, time::Instant};
use indicatif::{ParallelProgressIterator, ProgressStyle};
use rayon::prelude::*;
use tempfile::NamedTempFile;
use clap::Parser;

fn build_map(xd: usize, yd: usize) -> Vec<Vec<usize>> {
    let mut map = vec![vec![xd*yd;yd];xd];
    let mut x: isize = 0;
    let mut y: isize = 0;
    let mut dx: isize = 1;
    let mut dy: isize = 0;
    for i in (0..xd*yd).rev() {
        map[x as usize][y as usize] = i;
        let x1 = x+dx;
        let y1 = y+dy;
        if x1 < 0 || x1 >= isize::try_from(xd).unwrap() || y1 < 0 || y1 >= isize::try_from(yd).unwrap() || map[x1 as usize][y1 as usize] < xd*yd {
            let t = dy;
            dy = dx;
            dx = -t;
            x += dx;
            y += dy;
        } else {
            x = x1;
            y = y1;
        }
    }
    map
}

fn make_edges(dx: usize, dy: usize) -> Vec<Vec<usize>> {
    let n = dx * dy;
    let mut edges = vec![vec![n;n];4];
    let map = build_map(dx, dy);
    for x in 0..dx {
        for y in 0..dy {
            let idx = map[x][y];
            if x > 0 {
                let e = &mut edges[x%2];
                let idx1 = map[x-1][y];
                e[idx] = idx1;
                e[idx1] = idx;
            }
            if y > 0 {
                let e = &mut edges[2+(y%2)];
                let idx1 = map[x][y-1];
                e[idx] = idx1;
                e[idx1] = idx;
            }
        }
    }
    edges
}

fn get_good(l: &Vec<usize>, i: usize, edges: &Vec<Vec<usize>>) -> u64 {
    let mut good = u64::MAX >> (64 - i);
    for e in edges {
        let o = e[i];
        if o >= i {continue;}
        let mut temp = 1<<o;
        let mut j = l[o];
        while j != o {
            let j1 = e[j];
            if j1 < i {
                j = j1;
            }
            temp |= 1<<j;
            j = l[j];
        }
        good &= temp;
        if good == 0 {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    good
}

fn iter_good<F>(good: u64, l: &mut Vec<usize>, i: usize, mut f:F)
where F:FnMut(&mut Vec<usize>) {
    for j in 0..i {
        if good & (1<<j) > 0 {
            let lj = l[j];
            l[i] = lj;
            l[j] = i;
            f(l);
            l[j] = lj;
        }
    }
}

fn recurse_count(l: &mut Vec<usize>, i: usize, edges: &Vec<Vec<usize>>, n: usize) -> usize {
    let good = get_good(l, i, edges);
    if good == 0 {
        return 0;
    }
    if i == n-1 {
        return good.count_ones() as _;
    }
    let mut out = 0;
    iter_good(good, l, i, |l| {
        out += recurse_count(l, i+1, edges, n);
    });
    out
}

fn recurse_generate(l: &mut Vec<usize>, i: usize, edges: &Vec<Vec<usize>>, n: usize, out: &mut Vec<Vec<usize>>) {
    if i == n {
        out.push(l.clone());
        return;
    }
    let good = get_good(l, i, edges);
    if good == 0 {
        return;
    }
    iter_good(good, l, i, |l| {
        recurse_generate(l, i+1, edges, n, out);
    });
}

fn generate_permutations(c: usize) -> Vec<Vec<usize>> {
    let map = build_map(c, c);
    let mut reverse_map = vec![(0,0);c*c];
    for x in 0..c {
        for y in 0..c {
            reverse_map[map[x][y]] = (x, y);
        }
    }
    let mut out: Vec<Vec<usize>> = vec![];
    let d = c-1;
    out.push((0..c*c).map(|i|{let (x, y) = reverse_map[i]; map[  x][  y]}).collect());
    out.push((0..c*c).map(|i|{let (x, y) = reverse_map[i]; map[  y][  x]}).collect());
    out.push((0..c*c).map(|i|{let (x, y) = reverse_map[i]; map[  x][d-y]}).collect());
    out.push((0..c*c).map(|i|{let (x, y) = reverse_map[i]; map[  y][d-x]}).collect());
    out.push((0..c*c).map(|i|{let (x, y) = reverse_map[i]; map[d-x][  y]}).collect());
    out.push((0..c*c).map(|i|{let (x, y) = reverse_map[i]; map[d-y][  x]}).collect());
    out.push((0..c*c).map(|i|{let (x, y) = reverse_map[i]; map[d-x][d-y]}).collect());
    out.push((0..c*c).map(|i|{let (x, y) = reverse_map[i]; map[d-y][d-x]}).collect());
    out
}

fn permute(l: &Vec<usize>, c: usize, permutations: &Vec<Vec<usize>>) -> HashSet<Vec<usize>> {
    let mut out = HashSet::new();
    for p in permutations {
        let mut l1 = l.clone();
        for i in 0..c*c {
            let j = l[i];
            l1[p[i]] = p[j];
        }
        let mut l2 = l1.clone();
        let mut i = 0;
        while {
            l2[l1[i]] = i;
            i = l1[i];
            i != 0
        } {}
        out.insert(l1);
        out.insert(l2);
    }
    out
}

fn deduplicate_cases(cases: &Vec<Vec<usize>>, c: usize) -> Vec<(Vec<usize>, usize)>{
    let permutations = generate_permutations(c);
    let mut seen: HashSet<Vec<usize>> = HashSet::new();
    let mut out = vec![];
    for l in cases {
        if seen.contains(l) {continue;}
        let p = permute(l, c, &permutations);
        out.push((l.clone(), p.len()));
        seen.extend(p);
    }
    out
}

fn f(n: usize, save_file: Option<&PathBuf>, quiet: bool, save_frequency: u64) -> usize {
    if n <= 1 {
        return 1;
    }
    if n == 2 {
        return 8;
    }
    let n2 = n*n;
    let edges = make_edges(n, n);
    let mut l = vec![0; n2];
    l[0] = 1;
    l[1] = 2;
    l[2] = 0;
    if n <= 5 {
        return 2*n2*recurse_count(&mut l, 3, &edges, n2);
    }
    let mut cases = vec![];
    let c = match n%2 {
        0 => 4,
        1 => 3,
        _ => panic!("n%2 >= 2?")
    };
    let mut c2 = c*c;
    recurse_generate(&mut l, 3, &edges, c2, &mut cases);
    if !quiet {
        println!("Number of cases: {}", cases.len());
    }
    let mut cases = deduplicate_cases(&cases, c);
    if !quiet {
        println!("Reduced number of cases: {}", cases.len());
    }
    if n >= 7 {
        let expanded_n = match n {
            7 => 24,
            8 => 24,
            _ => panic!("too big")
        };
        let mut cases1 = vec![];
        for (mut l, m) in cases {
            let mut cases2 = vec![];
            recurse_generate(&mut l, c2, &edges, expanded_n, &mut cases2);
            cases1.extend(cases2.into_iter().map(|i|(i,m)));
        }
        cases = cases1;
        c2 = expanded_n;
        if !quiet {
            println!("Expanded number of cases: {}", cases.len());
        }
    }
    (match save_file {
        Some(file_name) => {
            if !fs::exists(file_name).unwrap() {
                fs::write(file_name, b"").unwrap();
            }

            let mut counts = bincode::deserialize::<(usize, Vec<Option<usize>>)>(&fs::read(&file_name).unwrap())
                .unwrap_or((0, vec![None; cases.len()]));
            if counts.1.len() != cases.len() {
                counts.0 = 0;
                counts.1 = vec![None; cases.len()];
            }
            if !quiet {
                println!("Already completed: {}", counts.0);
            }
            let counts_lock = Arc::new(Mutex::new(counts));
            let parent_dir = std::path::Path::new(file_name).parent().unwrap();
            let last_update = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Instant::now()));
            let it = cases
                .par_iter_mut()
                .enumerate()
                .map(|(idx, (l, m))| {
                    if let Some(v) = counts_lock.lock().unwrap().1[idx] {
                        return v;
                    }
                    let out = *m * recurse_count(l, c2, &edges, n2);
                    let mut counts = counts_lock.lock().unwrap();
                    counts.1[idx] = Some(out);
                    counts.0 += 1;
                    let mut inst = last_update.lock().unwrap();
                    if counts.0 == counts.1.len() || inst.elapsed().as_secs() > save_frequency {
                        *inst = Instant::now();
                        let s = bincode::serialize::<(usize, Vec<Option<usize>>)>(&*counts).unwrap();
                        let mut temp = NamedTempFile::new_in(parent_dir).unwrap();
                        temp.write_all(&s[..]).unwrap();
                        temp.persist(file_name).unwrap();
                    }
                    out
                });
            if quiet {
                it.sum::<usize>()
            } else {
                it
                    .progress_with_style(ProgressStyle::with_template("{wide_bar} {pos}/{len} ({elapsed}/{duration})").unwrap())
                    .sum::<usize>()
            }
        },
        None => {
            let it = cases
                .par_iter_mut()
                .map(|(l, m)| *m * recurse_count(l, c2, &edges, n2));
            if quiet {
                it.sum::<usize>()
            } else {
                it
                    .progress_with_style(ProgressStyle::with_template("{wide_bar} {pos}/{len} ({elapsed}/{duration})").unwrap())
                    .sum::<usize>()
            }
        }
    })*n2
}

#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[command(about, long_about = None)]
struct Cli {
    /// Side length of grid
    n: usize,
    /// File to save state to (only used if n>6)
    #[arg(short, long)]
    file: Option<PathBuf>,
    /// Maximum number of threads
    #[arg(short, long)]
    threads: Option<usize>,
    /// Disable extra logs and progress bar
    #[arg(short, long)]
    quiet: bool,
    /// Frequency to save state (in minutes)
    #[arg(short, long, default_value_t = 30)]
    duration: u64,
}

fn main() {
    let cli = Cli::parse();
    if let Some(num_threads) = cli.threads {
        rayon::ThreadPoolBuilder::new().num_threads(num_threads).build_global().unwrap();
    }
    let n = cli.n;
    let out = if n <= 6 {
        f(n, None, cli.quiet, cli.duration * 60)
    } else {
        f(n, cli.file.as_ref(), cli.quiet, cli.duration * 60)
    };
    println!("{n}x{n}: {}", out);
}

Cargo.toml
cargo-features = ["profile-rustflags"]

[package]
name = "map_folding"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
bincode = "1.3.3"
clap = { version = "4.5.21", features = ["derive"] }
indicatif = { version = "0.17.9", features = ["rayon"] }
rayon = "1.10.0"
tempfile = "3.14.0"

[profile.release]
rustflags = ["-C", "target-cpu=native"]

Build with cargo build -r (I'm using rustc 1.84.0-nightly).
Run with map_folding 7 --file folds_7 --threads 1 --duration 30 to count for a 7x7 grid, saving state in folds_7 every 30 minutes. (If you don't specify a file, it won't save).
This uses mostly the same algorithm as the linked paper. The main difference is that since this program is meant for square grids, there are 8 additional symmetries that can apply (Actually the paper mentions these in theorems 2.3 and 2.4, but it doesn't seem like the algorithm actually uses them). The symmetries are (mostly) eliminated by enumerating cycles involving the center 9 or 16 squares (depending on if n is odd or even respectively) and enumerating the equivalence classes (this is what the deduplicate_cases function does).

aa, I hadn't meant to restrict you to one thread when I mentioned the stats of the java program, I was just giving an example of how it behaved on my system. I'll put the time without using the --threads 1 option in the scoreboard. (same with the file option; the point of that is that I plan on setting the fastest response in the background for however long it needs to take)

I resumed the script and it says already completed is 92094 but the progress bar says 59626; is this expected?

@guest4308 It is expected and the missing cases are not lost. The order that rayon runs the cases isn't deterministic, so the already completed cases kind of get spread out in the order that cases wind up being completed. If you prefer, I can change it to count those cases first.

if that's expected then there's no problem; I was just wondering what happened. it does seem like it's faster rn; it's all the way back up to 73043 already; so basically it'll just be a bit faster until it looks over all the partially completed cases?

@guest4308 yes.

Python
Python port of @gsitcia's Rust answer.
Log
2024-11-29 Add numba.njit for acceleration

from multiprocessing import Pool
from numba import njit
from pathlib import Path
import argparse
import numpy as np
import pickle
import time

# Global variables to be initialized in each worker process
edges = None
n2 = None
c2 = None

def build_map(xd: int, yd: int) -> list:
    map_ = [[xd * yd for _ in range(yd)] for _ in range(xd)]
    x = 0
    y = 0
    dx = 1
    dy = 0
    for i in reversed(range(xd * yd)):
        map_[x][y] = i
        x1 = x + dx
        y1 = y + dy
        if (
            x1 < 0
            or x1 >= xd
            or y1 < 0
            or y1 >= yd
            or map_[x1][y1] < xd * yd
        ):
            t = dy
            dy = dx
            dx = -t
            x += dx
            y += dy
        else:
            x = x1
            y = y1
    return map_

def make_edges(dx: int, dy: int) -> np.ndarray:
    n = dx * dy
    edges = np.full((4, n), n, dtype=np.int64)
    map_ = build_map(dx, dy)
    for x in range(dx):
        for y in range(dy):
            idx = map_[x][y]
            if x > 0:
                e = edges[x % 2]
                idx1 = map_[x - 1][y]
                e[idx] = idx1
                e[idx1] = idx
            if y > 0:
                e = edges[2 + (y % 2)]
                idx1 = map_[x][y - 1]
                e[idx] = idx1
                e[idx1] = idx
    return edges

@njit
def count_bits(x):
    count = 0
    while x:
        count += x & 1
        x >>= 1
    return count

@njit
def get_good(l: np.ndarray, i: int, edges: np.ndarray) -> np.uint64:
    good = np.uint64((1 << i) - 1)
    for e in edges:
        o = e[i]
        if o >= i:
            continue
        temp = np.uint64(1 << o)
        j = l[o]
        while j != o:
            j1 = e[j]
            if j1 < i:
                j = j1
            temp |= np.uint64(1 << j)
            j = l[j]
        good &= temp
        if good == 0:
            return np.uint64(0)
    return good

@njit
def recurse_count(l: np.ndarray, i: int, edges: np.ndarray, n: int) -> int:
    good = get_good(l, i, edges)
    if good == 0:
        return 0
    if i == n - 1:
        return count_bits(good)
    out = 0
    for j in range(i):
        if good & (1 << j):
            lj = l[j]
            l[i] = lj
            l[j] = i
            out += recurse_count(l, i + 1, edges, n)
            l[j] = lj
    return out

def recurse_generate(l: list, i: int, edges: np.ndarray, n: int, out: list):
    if i == n:
        out.append(l.copy())
        return
    good = get_good(np.array(l), i, edges)
    if good == 0:
        return
    for j in range(i):
        if good & (1 << j):
            lj = l[j]
            l[i] = lj
            l[j] = i
            recurse_generate(l, i + 1, edges, n, out)
            l[j] = lj

def generate_permutations(c: int) -> list:
    map_ = build_map(c, c)
    reverse_map = [(0, 0) for _ in range(c * c)]
    for x in range(c):
        for y in range(c):
            reverse_map[map_[x][y]] = (x, y)
    out = []
    d = c - 1
    transformations = [
        lambda x, y: (x, y),
        lambda x, y: (y, x),
        lambda x, y: (x, d - y),
        lambda x, y: (y, d - x),
        lambda x, y: (d - x, y),
        lambda x, y: (d - y, x),
        lambda x, y: (d - x, d - y),
        lambda x, y: (d - y, d - x),
    ]
    for transform in transformations:
        perm = []
        for i in range(c * c):
            x, y = reverse_map[i]
            tx, ty = transform(x, y)
            perm.append(map_[tx][ty])
        out.append(perm)
    return out

def permute(l: list, c: int, permutations: list) -> set:
    out = set()
    for p in permutations:
        l1 = l.copy()
        for i in range(c * c):
            j = l[i]
            l1[p[i]] = p[j]
        l2 = l1.copy()
        i = 0
        while True:
            l2[l1[i]] = i
            i = l1[i]
            if i == 0:
                break
        out.add(tuple(l1))
        out.add(tuple(l2))
    return out

def deduplicate_cases(cases: list, c: int) -> list:
    permutations = generate_permutations(c)
    seen = set()
    out_cases = []
    for l in cases:
        l_tuple = tuple(l)
        if l_tuple in seen:
            continue
        p = permute(l, c, permutations)
        out_cases.append((l.copy(), len(p)))
        seen.update(p)
    return out_cases

def init_worker(_edges, _n2, _c2):
    global edges, n2, c2
    edges = _edges
    n2 = _n2
    c2 = _c2

def process_case(args):
    l_case, m = args
    l_case_np = np.array(l_case, dtype=np.int64)
    count = m * recurse_count(l_case_np, c2, edges, n2)
    return count

def f(n: int, save_file: Path, quiet: bool, save_frequency: int) -> int:
    global edges, c2, n2
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    if n == 2:
        return 8
    n2 = n * n
    edges = make_edges(n, n)
    l = [0] * n2
    l[0] = 1
    l[1] = 2
    l[2] = 0
    if n <= 5:
        return 2 * n2 * recurse_count(np.array(l, dtype=np.int64), 3, edges, n2)
    cases = []
    c = 4 if n % 2 == 0 else 3
    c2 = c * c
    recurse_generate(l, 3, edges, c2, cases)
    if not quiet:
        print(f"Number of cases: {len(cases)}")
    cases = deduplicate_cases(cases, c)
    if not quiet:
        print(f"Reduced number of cases: {len(cases)}")
    if n >= 7:
        expanded_n = 24 if n in (7, 8) else None
        if expanded_n is None:
            raise ValueError("n too big")
        cases1 = []
        for l_case, m in cases:
            cases2 = []
            recurse_generate(l_case, c2, edges, expanded_n, cases2)
            cases1.extend((l2, m) for l2 in cases2)
        cases = cases1
        c2 = expanded_n
        if not quiet:
            print(f"Expanded number of cases: {len(cases)}")
    counts_completed = 0
    last_save_time = time.time()
    total_count = 0
    counts = []

    save_frequency *= 60  # Convert to seconds

    def progress_report():
        if save_file:
            with open(save_file, 'wb') as f:
                pickle.dump((counts_completed, counts), f)
        if not quiet:
            print(f"Progress: {counts_completed}/{len(cases)} cases completed.")

    # Prepare edges and variables for multiprocessing
    edges_shared = edges  # edges is already a NumPy array, which is picklable
    n2_shared = n2
    c2_shared = c2

    with Pool(initializer=init_worker, initargs=(edges_shared, n2_shared, c2_shared)) as pool:
        counts_completed = 0
        total_count = 0
        last_save_time = time.time()
        for count in pool.imap_unordered(process_case, cases):
            counts_completed += 1
            total_count += count
            counts.append(count)
            current_time = time.time()
            if counts_completed == len(cases) or current_time - last_save_time > save_frequency:
                progress_report()
                last_save_time = current_time

    return total_count * n2

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process grid configurations.')
    parser.add_argument('n', type=int, help='Side length of grid')
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--file', type=Path, help='File to save state to (only used if n>6)')
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--threads', type=int, help='Maximum number of threads')
    parser.add_argument('-q', '--quiet', action='store_true', help='Disable extra logs and progress bar')
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--duration', type=int, default=30, help='Frequency to save state (in minutes)')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    n = args.n
    save_file = args.file
    quiet = args.quiet
    duration = args.duration  # Already in minutes

    result = f(n, save_file, quiet, duration)
    print(f"{n}x{n}: {result}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Attempt This Online!

I just set the other solution running for #8 with most of my compute, so I'll wait for it to save and then run yours; but restricting everything to one thread, the rust answer gets around .8 s, the java solution gets around 5s, and yours gets around 51s for case #5
